# Best javascript library to create and interactive flow chart

Tags: javascript, raphael, flowchart

I would like to create an interactive 'problem solving' type flow chart that is made up out div elements.

I would like to do something very similar to what the new york times have done in this example...

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/06/14/us/how-the-supreme-court-could-rule-on-the-health-care-law.html?ref=us

Someone suggested Raphael so I've been learning a bit of that and it's awesome.

Is there any other library worth considering?

Also if Raphael is suitable for this task, is it a widely used library? If I am going to learn new skills It's in my best interest to learn popular code so I can re apply it with different jobs I get, not some exotic thing that Ill never use or no one will ever want me to use again.

Comment: Hey @Dale, what did you settle on? I want to know what all is out there for visualizing an "interactive decision tree" thing like the NY Times page. I think the answers here are good to roll our own, but seems like for such a common thing, there should be more tools out there to just plug in tree data and start skinning. If not, are you interested on working on something open source? 

I want to create a beginning farmer's guide on making good decisions based on soil type, rainfall, PH, crop you want to plant, etc. to let new farmers easily learn how to prep soil.

Comment: i *hate* when the overlords close stuff. This is incredibly constructive, overlords, please stop doing this.

Answer (score 5):

Consider [D3JS](http://d3js.org/) if you want to dive into data visualization. There are tons of nice example and tutorials on the website.

PS: The create Mike Bostock current works for NY Times as far as I know ;)

Comment: Not sure how d3js is good for flow charts. Flow charts have a lot of structure involved and making it using a tabular data file would be difficult. Please provide an example to illustrate it ?

Answer (score 3):

For something truly as simple as the NYTimes example there's nothing stopping you from doing it with a few images of arrows and [jquery .slideDown()](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown#speedcallback). It'd sure be lighter than using a bigger vector library, and it'd work in browsers old as salt.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) js library is powerful. Also I can suggest to take a look to [ExtJs 4](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/#sample-3) - it has cool examples too (of course if you need something else from it, not only charts)...